# Render Field from FieldHandler in FreeForm Craft CMS

Tags: craft3, plugin-freeform, freeform

Can we render some particular field from our FreeForm plugin ?

If yes, how can we achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

To pull an individual field from a form, use the `form.get("myFieldHandle")` method.

Simple example using the [field.render()](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/template-objects/field.html#methods) method:

```
{% set form = craft.freeform.form("myFormHandle") %}

{{ form.get("firstName").render() }}
```

Or a more custom example:

```
{% set form = craft.freeform.form("myFormHandle") %}
{% set firstName = form.get("firstName") %}

<label>{{ firstName.label }}</label>
<input name="{{ firstName.handle }}" value="{{ firstName.value }}" />
{{ firstName.renderErrors() }}
```

[Examples from Freeform documentation](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/template-functions/freeform.form.html#usage-in-templates)

Note from the Freeform's docs:

> When using with HTML blocks or Submit buttons, use the hash value provided in property editor in Composer as the handle. Example code would look like:
>   {{ form.get('Ajx7jNxXL').render }}